# How to get the value of the margin of a border?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I'm a beginner in WPF and have to add functionality to someone's user interface. Here's part of the code.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="1" >
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=passFailIndicator, Path=Width}"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Background="Black" local:StretchPanel.Proportion="1" Name="imageBorder" Grid.Column="0">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" Margin="2" BorderBrush="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ElementName=imageBorder, Path=Width}">
                    <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=imageBorder, Path=Width}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=imageSelectExpander, Path=Width}"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Column="0" x:Name="image" Source="{Binding DisplayImage, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Left" StretchDirection="Both" MouseMove="image_MouseMove" />
                        <TextBlock Name="pxPos" Text="mouse position" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" MaxHeight="20" Foreground="Aqua"></TextBlock>
                        <Expander Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="imageSelectExpander">
                            <ComboBox x:Name="imageSelect" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableImages, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedIndex="{Binding ImageSelect, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="4" Padding="4" MaxHeight="40"></ComboBox>
                        </Expander>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Border>
            <Border x:Name="passFailIndicator" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="100">
                <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" >
                    <Path Style="{Binding TestResult, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource testResultToPathStyle}}" Margin="2" />
                </Viewbox>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

I'm trying to access the Margin="2" on line 10. When I use this.imageBorder.Margin, I get {0,0,0,0}. How would I get the 2 (of course, this value may change)?

thanks

edit:

```
FrameworkElement fe = (FrameworkElement)this.imageBorder.Child;
            pxPos.Text = (string.Format("x:{0} y:{1}", (int)((double)(pt.X - fe.Margin.Left) * (double)this.image.Source.Width / this.image.ActualWidth), (int)((double)(pt.Y - fe.Margin.Top)*(double)this.image.Source.Height / this.image.ActualHeight)));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Border labeled `imageBorder` does not have its `Margin` property set to anything, so you are getting the default `Margin`, which is 0.

To get the Margin property of the Border inside your named border, either give it an `x:Name` so you can access it in code behind, or look in `imageBorder.Child` property to find the child Border object, then cast it to a `FrameworkElement` to get its Margin property.

As for why you're getting `{0,0,0,0}`, the [Margin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx) property is of type [Thickness](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness.aspx), which consists of properties for Left, Top, Right, and Bottom. If you set a margin to a single value, such as 2, it automatically converts that to a `Thickness` object with all 4 of its properties set to 2.

Comment: thanks, i'll explicitly write down the code in case someone else one day looks for it